# POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to make my patient book for an appointment. I am using 2 controllers: **PatientController** and **AppointmentController**.

**PatientController.php**

```
public function book()
{
    $patients = new User(); 
    return view('patient.patient_book', compact('patients'));
}
```

**AppointmentController.php**

```
public function store(){
    $patient = new User();
    $appointment = new Appointment();

    $appointment->user_id = $patient->id;
    $appointment->appointment_date = request('date_booking');
    $appointment->slot = request('slot');
    $appointment->branch = request('branch');
    $appointment->note = request('note');
    $appointment->save();
    return redirect('/patient/report_list');
}
```

As for my **route**;

```
Route::prefix('patient')->group(function(){
     Route::get('/patient_book', 'PatientController@book');
     Route::post('/report_list', "AppointmentController@store");
});
```

I have also included the relationship inside **User** model

```
protected $guarded = [];

public function appointments(){

    return $this->hasMany(Appointment::class);
}
```

And as for the **Appointment** model;

```
protected $guarded = [];

public function patient(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Inside my **patient_book.blade.php**;

```
<form method = "POST" action = "/patient/report_list">
```

After the form has been submitted, it needs to be redirected to report_list.blade.php where the newly submitted appointment will be listed on that page. I followed the tutorial in Laracasts where the examples used are Project and Task. However, I received this error when I tried to run it.

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

I have checked on the other answers but nothing seemed to help. Please help me as I am still new and confused with Laravel. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here

```
return redirect('/patient/report_list');
```

You can't return a 301 redirect response to a POST route, it has to be a GET route

You may want to redirect to previous page instead

```
return back();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. But I have a new error. After I did that, there's a new error that says: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Appointment' not found" and it points to "$appointment = new Appointment();" .  Does it have to do with the table 'appointments'?

Comment: Thank you, it removes that error. I have another question though, why is it that even if input has already been key in, there's an error that says, SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'slot' cannot be null ? Even though it has already requested from the form submitted and I wrote it like this; $appointment->slot = request()->get('slot');
Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: I have it in my HTML.  I searched for similar problems in here, and it doesn't solve my problem yet. The person also faced the same error. My HTML is like this:
<select class="form-control" name = 'slot'>
                        <option>Select time slot</option>
                        <option value = "09:00">09:00</option>
                        <option value = "09:30">09:30</option>
                        <option value = "10:00">10:00</option>
</select>

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, I didn't change anything in the HTML. I just tried dd($appointment->slot) and it's actually not null. After I tried once again, the data finally went through. Thank you so much for the help!